# connection pool - SQLAlchemy & Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I have a situation. I am having a code which uses SQLAlchemy for database activities. And have application made in flask, flask_restful to access the db codes. Now while testing, through unittest, i am facing some issues. And i m sure it is because Flask keeps the connection open after a request completes. So i want to implement connection pooling in my codes to check.I went through the connection pooling official docs of SQLAlchemy. And here are my questios -

- So in docs it is written that by default SQLAlchemy offers connection pooling with defaults, like max_pool_size = 5, max_overflow = 10. So my question is do i need to pass the parameter like this = cnx = create_engine('connection string', pool=queuepool) to envoke that default behavior or simple create_enine('connection string') will do that?
- Do we have any class\function in flask package to do connection polling?
- can anyone share any code\project link which has this setup?(some practical scenario will be helpful not any sample example)

Comment: *Whoa*, back up. Please add some structure to your post so we can read it. I'm getting a headache trying to read all that.

Comment: @connectyourcharger Have edited my question. Is it clear now? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy does connection pooling by default, which means it will do that behaviour without specifying it, `create_engine('connection_string')` will be enough.

You **can** choose a specific pooling class if you like: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#switching-pool-implementations

That can be used to disable the pooling entirely with the `NullPool`.

From SQLAlchemy docs:

```py
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
engine = create_engine(
          'postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/test',
          poolclass=NullPool)
```